# How to monitor freeradius using EAP-MSCHAP v2 authentication method with Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, authentication, nagios, radius

How to monitor freeradius using EAP-MSCHAP v2 authentication method with Nagios? Do you know any nagios plugins for such monitoring?

Answer (score 2):

I have nagios setup to monitor radius, if I remember right all that is required is to have the servers defined in `/etc/radiusclient/servers` and then..

```
define command{
    command_name    check_our_radius
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_radius -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u username -p password -F /etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf -t 10 -P 1812
}
```

then use that as a check_command like any other service.

This has the password in the config file and on the commandline, but if you have a dedicated nagios box and test user like me this isn't much of an issue.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I monitor a freeradius server with the above config, does that somehow not answer this question?

Comment: I don't believe that will be able to use EAP-MSCHAP v2 though?

Answer (score 0):

There is rad_eap_test. It uses `eapol_test` to authenticate with EAP MS-CHAPv2.

https://github.com/CESNET/rad_eap_test